# Receiving simple ajax responses in rails 4 app ruby 2.1.2 on heroku takes over a minute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, heroku, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an app running rails 4.0.4 on heroku using ruby 2.1.2. On the homepage is a link that makes a remote request to the new action of an invitations controller. This deposits a form for the user to add their email to a mailing list. When the user hits submit on this form the invitations controller renders either a success message or an error message. Waiting for that response takes over a minute. It's two lines of js.

In chrome's network tab all the timing is - Blocking: 0.8ms, Sending: 0.2ms, Waiting: 222ms, Receiving: 59s.

I initially thought it was some type of memory issue with my ruby/ rails setup so I tried downgrading to ruby 2.0 from 2.1, that didn't work so I upgraded to 2.1.2 (in the process I found out 2.1.1 is deprecated on heroku anyhow).

I also thought the PaperTrail addon might be causing problems so I switched to Logger with not luck.

I have no idea what the issue is, or what information to supply here. Please let me know what info to add here and I'll gladly supply it.

Comment: Possibly related to my [post here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24717495/slow-page-load-on-heroku)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found information on Twitter.

this seems to be related to websockets.  Disabling it seems to cure the issues.

```
heroku labs:disable websockets -a myapp -p production
```

this makes it work as it used to, though the logs now look different :)

thanks to @dwaynemac @stephane_tavera on twitter.

**EDIT**:

Heroku shows this as a resolve issue, but answer applies in case it happens again.

https://status.heroku.com/incidents/649#update-2163

Comment: Ya, glad it was fixed, I spent hours thinking I broke something since I had just updated the code.